# Trying to create a memory game with JS

Tags: javascript

```js
const CELLS = document.getElementsByClassName("cell"); /// Getting the cells from the HTML
let counter = -1; /// Counter so I can go over each level.
let level = [
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
]; /// There are 4 empty levels in the array which are going to be filled eventually with random numbers representing the index of the cells


function generateLvl(n) /// filling the level with n number of index values
{
  counter++;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    level[counter].push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * (n - 0) + 0));
  }
}

function showCell(index) /// receives the index and highlights the cell for few milliseconds 
{
  CELLS[index].classList.add("active");
  setTimeout(() => {
    CELLS[index].classList.remove("active");
  }, 750);
}

function showLevel() /// shows the level
{
  for (let i = 0; i < level[counter].length; i++) {
    showCell(level[counter][i]); /// calls showCell function and sends values of the current level to highlight its cells
  }
}
generateLvl(3);
showLevel();
```

```css
.game-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.game-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
}

.cell {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <title>Memory Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="game-box">
    <div class="game-table">
      <div class="cell cell-1"></div>
      <div class="cell cell-2"></div>
      <div class="cell cell-3"></div>
      <div class="cell cell-4"></div>
      <div class="cell cell-5"></div>
      <div class="cell cell-6"></div>
      <div class="cell cell-7"></div>
      <div class="cell cell-8"></div>
      <div class="cell cell-9"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./js/game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to create a game where the player is supposed to click on the boxes and repeat the order after the computer. There are 9 cells and once the game starts the player sees highlighted cells by the order which he is supposed to repeat.
The problem is that with my code all the cells are highlighted at once while they are supposed to be highlighted separately with few seconds between them. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `setTimeout...` piece of code is not awaited, it works asynchronoulsy.

My approach would be to wrap `showCell` function into [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```js
async function showCell(index) {

    const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        CELLS[index].classList.add("active");
        setTimeout(() => {
            CELLS[index].classList.remove("active");
            resolve();
        }, 750);
    });

    return promise;

}
```

Then you have to await this promise at each step in your for-loop:

```js
async function showLevel() /// shows the level
{
  for (let i = 0; i < level[counter].length; i++) {
    await showCell(level[counter][i]);
  //^^^^^ await here is important

  }
}
```